# How to Top 20 Word from text in java

Tags: java, hadoop

I need to read each line in the text file to find Top 20 words, 
The code takes argument  for Student ID to select 10,000 random line from a file.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.*;

public class MP1 {

    Random generator;
    String userName;
    String inputFileName;

    String delimiters = " \t,;.?!-:@[](){}_*/";


    String[] stopWordsArray = {"i", "me", "my", "myself", "we", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "you", "your", "yours",
            "yourself", "yourselves", "he", "him", "his", "himself", "she", "her", "hers", "herself", "it", "its",
            "itself", "they", "them", "their", "theirs", "themselves", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that",
            "these", "those", "am", "is", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", "have", "has", "had", "having",
            "do", "does", "did", "doing", "a", "an", "the", "and", "but", "if", "or", "because", "as", "until", "while",
            "of", "at", "by", "for", "with", "about", "against", "between", "into", "through", "during", "before",
            "after", "above", "below", "to", "from", "up", "down", "in", "out", "on", "off", "over", "under", "again",
            "further", "then", "once", "here", "there", "when", "where", "why", "how", "all", "any", "both", "each",
            "few", "more", "most", "other", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "not", "only", "own", "same", "so", "than",
            "too", "very", "s", "t", "can", "will", "just", "don", "should", "now"};


    void initialRandomGenerator(String seed) throws   
        NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        messageDigest.update(seed.toLowerCase().trim().getBytes());
        byte[] seedMD5 = messageDigest.digest();

        long longSeed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < seedMD5.length; i++) {
            longSeed += ((long) seedMD5[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);
        }

        this.generator = new Random(longSeed);
    }

    Integer[] getIndexes() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Integer n = 10000;
        Integer number_of_lines = 50000;
        Integer[] ret = new Integer[n];
        this.initialRandomGenerator(this.userName);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ret[i] = generator.nextInt(number_of_lines);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public MP1(String userName, String inputFileName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.inputFileName = inputFileName;
    }

    public String[] process() throws Exception {
        String[] ret = new String[20];

        //TODO


        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 1){
            System.out.println("MP1 <User ID>");
        }
        else {
            String userName = args[0];
            String inputFileName = "./input.txt";
            MP1 mp = new MP1(userName, inputFileName);
            String[] topItems = mp.process();
            for (String item: topItems){
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to insert Top 20 words inside the array rest and return it.
I wrote code to read file in each line, but don't know how to call getIndex() function to generate the line and to count top 20 words, also need to Ignore all common words provided in the “stopWordsArray” variable.  :-

```
public String[] process() throws Exception {
    String[] ret = new String[20];

    //TODO
     FileReader in = new FileReader(inputFileName);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
     String line = br.readLine();


    return ret;
}
```

I appreciate for your help.

Thanks,

Comment: "I don't know how to do it" isn't really a question. What specific problem have you encountered in your attempt at solving this yourself?

Comment: To get you started, you have the list of delimiters, and want to read a file, so use a `Scanner`. Don't know why you'd need a random generator for any of this. Use a `Map<String, Integer>` to map the words (String), and increment the counter (Integer). Better yet, implement your own `UpdatableInteger` so you don't have to create a new `Integer` object ever time you increment the counter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code for your solution looks like that:

```
public String[] process() throws Exception {
        String[] ret = new String[20];

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        FileReader in = new FileReader(inputFileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiters + " ");

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
                if (!Arrays.asList(stopWordsArray).contains(token))
                    if (map.containsKey(token)) {
                        map.put(token, map.get(token) + 1);
                    } else
                        map.put(token, 1);
                    }
        }
        br.close();
        for(int i=0;i<ret.length;i++){
            int max=0;
            String word="";
            for(Entry<String,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
                if(entry.getValue()>max){
                    max=entry.getValue();
                    word=entry.getKey();
                }
            }
            map.remove(word);
            ret[i]=word;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is very helpful. Thank you.